# 403 You are not permitted to execute the promotion 'snapshotToRelease'

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am trying to release a specific version via artifactory. Promoting to a release folder gives me a 403 error with below error:

```json
{
 "errors" : [ {
   "status" : 403,
   "message" : "You are not permitted to execute the promotion 'snapshotToRelease'."
 } ]
}
```

Looking at the error it's a permission issue and I have tried most of the permissions for the user that tries to release the build but no luck. Below is the api resource I'm trying to execute

`/api/plugins/build/promote/snapshotToRelease`

Comment: Which version of Artifactory are you using?

Comment: Artifactory Professional
6.7.0 rev 60700900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're using [this plugin](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/build/promotion/promotion.groovy#L66)?

The way this promotion is configured, only the following users can run it:

- Users with `admin` privileges
- A user with the username "`jenkins`"

If neither of these describe the user in question, and you're allowed to edit the plugin file, you can change the code to work with other users:

```
snapshotToRelease(users: ["my-promoter"], params: ...) { buildName, buildNumber, params ->
    // ...
}
```

Or any user in a group:

```
snapshotToRelease(groups: ["my-promote-group"], params: ...) { buildName, buildNumber, params ->
    // ...
}
```

(See the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Promotions) for more details.)

Comment: it's still the same error? If you're not the one who deployed the plugin, whoever did might have changed it to use a different user, or something.

Comment: Same error. I have less access to artifactory. I'm checking with them. thank you